# Replace URL value with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<div class='tile'>
    <a href='http://test-site.local' >
        <div class='tileContents'>
            <div class='tileImage'>
                <i class='icon-'></i>
            </div>
            <div class='tileCaption'>
                <h4>Logos</h4>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class='tile'>
    <a href='http://test-site.local' >
        <div class='tileContents'>
            <div class='tileImage'>
                <i class='icon-'></i>
            </div>
            <div class='tileCaption'>
                <h4>Adverts</h4>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I would like to update the `href` property to any URL I wish using the values of the `h4` tags as a way to target and differentiate the two DIVs as these have the same class name.

So for example I would like to update the URL in the a tag of the first div to:

```
<a  href="http://www.google.com">

so if the value of the h4 tag = "Logos" then update the URL to "http://www.google.com"
```

And the same for the second DIV:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">

so if the value of the h4 tag = "Adverts" then update the URL to "http://www.yahoo.com"
```

I have the following but I don't think I am getting the selectors correctly:

```
<script src="/script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
    var value = $('div.tile h4').html();
    if (value = "Logos");
    $("DIV.tile a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com");
    if (value = "Adverts");
    $("DIV.tile a").attr("href", "http://www.yahoo.com");
});
</script>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
$('div.tile').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).find('a:first');
    a.attr('href', a.attr('href') +'/'+ $(this).find('.tileCaption h4').text());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7qLgP/)

**Update :** After a long chat with `OP` I got what was the requirement and this is the solution :

```
var urls = {
    'Logos':'http://www.google.com/',
    'Adverts':'http://www.yahoo.com/'
};

$('div.tile').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).find('a:first');
    a.attr('href', urls[$(this).find('.tileCaption h4').text()]);
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7qLgP/14/)

Comment: This worked perfectly and without using if statements.  My jquery worked in updating the URLs but it was setting the same URL for all the divs. Excellent answer

Comment: Lastly what if I wanted to change the URL to something different than the value of the h4 tag? I now remember why I was using the if statement in the first place..

Comment: @DanielPerez, Here `$(this).find('.tileCaption h4').text()` is adding the `h4` text, so you may change this part with the content you want to replace.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think this will give the same URL to the a tag on both DIVs. What I need to do is to be able to do is to give different URL values to the a tags in the DIVs if that makes sense

Comment: @DanielPerez, Maybe i'm confused bur `a.attr('href')` part is adding the source `url(href", "http://test-site.local)` then `+'/'+` adds the `slash` and then `$(this).find('.tileCaption h4').text()` adds the rest from the `h4`, so if it makes you clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38920/discussion-between-daniel-perez-and-recovering-since-2003)

Comment: Welcome and I appreciate the green tick :-)

Answer (score 3):

Go through every tile and change its `children('a')`'s href

```
$('.tile').each(function(){
   $(this).children('a').attr("href", "http://test-site.local/"+$(this).find('h4').text());
});
```

The difference between `.find()` and `.children()` is that `.find()` finds what you want inside the element while `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree (so it's faster).

Use `.text()` to get the word and simply put it behind the url rather than using if statements (so it will be faster).

Answer (score 1):

First off : the correct selector syntax for a class attribute is `.className`, not `#className` (`#className` would search for a node who's *id* is "className").

Then : you should iterate through your nodes, and repeatedly call a function on each one of them. Use the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) function :

```
$('.tile').each(function(){
     //when this function executes, 'this' points to the current node

     // $(this).find(...) will look only through the descendants of 'this'
     var h4 = $(this).find('h4').html();

     $(this).find('a').attr('href', "http://test-site.local/"+h4 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tile').each(function () {
    $('> a', this).attr('href', function(){
        return this.href + $(this).find('h4').text();
    });
});
```